# How to get same search result if i filter a value with hyphen or without hyphen or with white spaces in queryset field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I need to get the same result when i search a word with or without a hyphen as well as white space in django queryset field.What should i do to satisfy this.

Eg. Queryset.objects.filter(type__icontains="T shirt").all()

The value i stored is "T-Shirts",
so how can i get this result from filtering

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your use case a little more?

You can try doing the following -

- Store the value of type in a variable. I am assuming you are fetching the value of type from the request.

```
value = request.data.get("type")
value = value.replace(" ", "-")

queryset = Queryset.objects.filter(type=value).all()
```